# How to implement perfect forwarding on a non-generic type?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

say I have the following code:

```
class Element;
typedef shared_ptr<Element> ElementPtr;

class Element
{
public:
    void add_child(const ElementPtr& elem);

private:
    vector<ElementPtr> children;
}

inline void Element::add_child(const ElementPtr& elem)
{
    children.push_back(elem);
};
```

And I want to update `add_child` to use perfect forwarding. I tried changing the function definition (and declaration) so use the following logic:

```
void Element::add_child(ElementPtr&& elem)
{
    children.push_back(forward<ElementPtr>(elem));
}
```

But this crashes for any call in which the argument `elem` is an lvalue. So I thought I'd try it with templates and came up with the following:

```
template <ElementPtr elem>
void Element::add_child(ElementPtr&& elem)
{
    children.push_back(forward<ElementPtr>(elem));
}
```

...But this does not compile. So I changed it to this:

```
template <class T>
void Element::add_child(T&& elem)
{
    children.push_back(forward<T>(elem));
}
```

...Which compiles and works, but seems ugly and improper; `add_child` will only ever accept arguments of type `ElementPtr`, so shouldn't its function declaration reflect this?

Is there any way to implement perfect forwarding for a function while syntactically demonstrating that it only accepts one kind of variable? I basically want a function that will automatically distinguish between lvalue and rvalue versions of a specific parameter type.

Answer (score 4):

Your options are

1. Use two overloads (aka "what `vector::push_back` does"):

   ```
   void add_child(const ElementPtr& elem) { children.push_back(elem); }
   void add_child(ElementPtr&& elem) { children.push_back(std::move(elem)); }
   ```
2. Use a single overload that takes its argument by value:

   ```
   void add_child(ElementPtr elem) { children.push_back(std::move(elem)); }
   ```
3. SFINAE.

   ```
   template <class T,
             class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<ElementPtr, std::decay_t<T>>{}>>
   void Element::add_child(T&& elem)
   {
       children.push_back(forward<T>(elem));
   }
   ```

Option 2 costs up to one additional move, but moving `shared_ptr`s is cheap since you don't need to touch the reference count. Option 1 is efficient, but subject to combinatorial explosion. Option 3 is also efficient, but is more difficult to read and maintain.