# Applying C++11 move semantics to bound functions

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, boost-bind, boost-function

I have some existing C++98 code that makes use of `boost::function` and `boost:bind` for asynchronous callbacks.  Some relevant simplified fragments of the code include:

```
typedef boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code, size_t)> WriteHandler;

struct WriteOperation
{
    WriteOperation(const boost::shared_ptr<IDevice>& device,
                   const std::string& data, const WriteHandler& handler)
        : m_Device(device), m_Data(data), m_Handler(handler) {}

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<IDevice> m_Device;
    std::string m_Data;
    WriteHandler m_Handler;

    void Complete()
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        size_t len;
        ...
        Async::Post(boost::bind(m_Handler, ec, len));
    }
};

struct Device : public IDevice
{
    void Write(const std::string& data, const WriteHandler& callback)
    {
        ...
        Async::Start(new WriteOperation(shared_from_this(), data,
            boost::bind(&Device::HandleWrite, this, handler, _1, _2)));
    }

 private:
    void HandleWrite(const WriteHandler& callback,
                     boost::system::error_code ec, size_t len)
    {
        ...
        callback(ec, len);
    }
};
```

There is one required copy, when constructing the `WriteOperation`, but other than that I'm trying to avoid copies since they can be quite expensive.

I'm pondering how this should best be written in the C++11 world.  The obvious low-hanging fruit is that the `WriteOperation` constructor internally copies its arguments to its fields, so should use the automatic copying idiom:

```
WriteOperation(boost::shared_ptr<IDevice> device,
               std::string data, WriteHandler handler)
    : m_Device(std::move(device)), m_Data(std::move(data)), m_Handler(std::move(handler))
{}
```

(And of course the bare `new` should be replaced with `unique_ptr`, but that's a side issue.)

However I don't think this actually gains anything given the current implementation of `Device::Write`, so that ought to change too.  My problem is that I don't really see a good way to do it.  According to [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960428/43534), I have three options:

1. Declare multiple overloads (one with `const&` and one with `&&`) -- but since this has two parameters, both of which could benefit from move semantics, this would require four overloads -- getting exponentially worse for methods with more parameters.  Additionally this leads to either code duplication or scattering the code over additional methods, which can impair readability.
2. Pass by value and move (similar to the `WriteOperation` constructor).  This is perhaps the cleanest option when the body always makes a copy, which is true if the `WriteOperation` constructor is actually called, but what if the elided section contains logic that might return without constructing a `WriteOperation`?  There's a wasted copy in this case.
3. Template and perfect forward.  This requires an ugly SFINAE hack that confuses Intellisense and impairs readability (or worse, leaving the parameter type unconstrained), and requires that the implementation be put into the header, which is sometimes undesirable.  *And* it interferes with type conversions, eg. a SFINAE `enable_if` `is_same` looking for `std::string` will not accept a `const char *` literal, while the original `const&` version will.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better solution?  Or is this just a case where move semantics don't make any difference?

---

A related case:

```
typedef boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code, const std::string&)> ReadHandler;

void Read(const ReadHandler& callback)
{
    ... boost::bind(&Device::HandleRead, this, callback, _1, _2) ...
}

void HandleRead(const ReadHandler& callback,
                boost::system::error_code ec, const std::string& data)
{
    ...
    callback(ec, data);
}
```

This all seems like it should be ok, with no copying and no need for move semantics.  And yet again I'm unsure about the `ReadHandler` passed to `Read`.

Comment: "since this has two parameters, both of which could benefit from move semantics", which are those? In your example code you're treating all three arguments as benefiting from move semantics.

Comment: `Device::Write` has only two parameters.  The `WriteOperation` constructor has a third parameter but since this is passed `shared_from_this()` it will always be copied anyway.

Comment: Well, how likely is it that `Device::Write` will be called with temporaries as actual arguments, and how important to optimize that case?

Comment: If you follow the call chain up far enough, it ends at a local variable (which is not used further after the call), so possibly always, assuming those intermediate layers also move.  As for how important it is, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

In rough order:

If copy is just as expensive as move, take it by `const&`.

If you reliably keep a copy, and move is cheap, take by value.

Failing that, you can stuff it in a header and are ok with sfinae or unconstrained templates, use forwarding references.

Failing that, if there are a limited number of arguments, write each overload.  This is `2^n` in the number of parameters, so there better not be too many.  Forward internally to a forwarding reference based implementation.

Failing that, do you really need efficiency here?

Failing that, type erase to "creator of `T`".

```
template<class T, using Base=std::function<T()>>
struct creator_of: Base
{
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, U&&>{},int> =0
  >
  creator_of(U&&u):
    Base([&]()->T{ return std::forward<U>(u); })
  {}
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<U>()>{},int> =0
  >
  creator_of(U&&u):
    Base(std::forward<U>(u))
  {}

  creator_of(creator_of&&)=default;
  creator_of():
    Base([]()->T{return {};}}
  {}
};
```

augment as needed.  A `creator_of<std::string>` can be constructed from things that can construct a `std::string`, or from a function object returning a `std::string`.

Internally you can call `()` once on it.

(Code not compiled, but design is sound.)

Comment: "Move is cheap" is an important consideration.  Most discussion I can find on the constructor-by-value idiom fail to mention that it can perform two copies if the type defines a copy constructor without an explicit (deleted or not) move constructor (ie. most existing C++98 types), and is thus worse by default on those types.

Comment: This does not address the OP's concern "but what if the elided section contains logic that might return without constructing a WriteOperation? There's a wasted copy in this case". Also, the `creator_of` code needs fleshing out with a real usage example.

Comment: @cheers if the `creator_of` is not invoked, no copy is performed. How does that not address the issue?  A similar case is true of every one of the fallbacks except "do you need efficiency" and "reliably keep a copy" solutions.

Comment: As I see it, although that's not necessarily the case at hand, in general the decision of whether to store the values or not, can depend on the argument values. Copying an argument just to inspect it is high cost. I think your approach is better than mine for modern C++, at least if one trusts the compiler to optimize those functors, but it doesn't yet address that issue.

Comment: @cheer if you do away with the "take a lambda" feature, adding a `.inspect()` method is easy.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the combinatorial explosion, while supporting the case where it turns out inside the called function that no argument copies are needed, you can *defer* the copying.

That's effectively a lazy evaluation scheme, but for this special case only.

With a support class like the one below one needs to be keenly aware that an instance might just hold a pointer to a short-lived caller's object. I.e., don't move a `Lazy_copy_` into storage that outlives the call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <utility>          // std::move, std::forward
using namespace std;

//------------------------------------ Machinery:

#ifdef TRACE
    inline void trace( string const& s )
    {
        clog << ": " << s << endl;
    }
#else
    inline void trace( string const& ) {}
#endif

struct Emplace {};

template< class Item >
class Lazy_copy_
{
private:
    Item const* p_callers_item_;
    union{ Item item_copy_; };      // Left uninitialized if p_callers_item_.

    void ensure_is_copy()
    {
        if( p_callers_item_ )
        {
            ::new( &item_copy_ ) Item( *p_callers_item_ );
            trace( "ensure_is_copy: made copy" );
            p_callers_item_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

public:
    auto item() const
        -> Item const&
    { return (p_callers_item_? *p_callers_item_ : item_copy_); }

    auto item_copy()
        -> Item&
    {
        ensure_is_copy();
        return item_copy_;
    }

    ~Lazy_copy_()
    {
        if( not p_callers_item_ ) { item_copy_.Item::~Item(); }
    }

    Lazy_copy_( Lazy_copy_ const& other )
        : p_callers_item_( other.p_callers_item_ )
    {
        if( p_callers_item_ )
        {
            ensure_is_copy();
        }
        else
        {
            ::new( &item_copy_ ) Item( other.item_copy_ );
            trace( "<init>( Lazy_copy ): made copy" );
        }
    }

    Lazy_copy_( Lazy_copy_&& other )
        : p_callers_item_( other.p_callers_item_ )
    {
        if( not p_callers_item_ )
        {
            ::new( &item_copy_ ) Item( move( other.item_copy_ ) );
            trace( "<init>( Lazy_copy&& ): moved" );
        }
    }

    Lazy_copy_( Item const& item )
        : p_callers_item_( &item )
    {}

    Lazy_copy_( Item&& temp_item )
        : p_callers_item_( nullptr )
        , item_copy_( move( temp_item ) )
    {
        trace( "<init>( Item&& ): moved" );
    }

    template< class... Args >
    Lazy_copy_( Emplace, Args&&... args )
        : p_callers_item_( nullptr )
        , item_copy_( forward<Args>( args )... )
    {
        trace( "<init>( Emplace, Args... ): Created item from constructor args" );
    }
};

//------------------------------------ Example usage:

struct Thingy
{
    string a, b, c;

    void foo(
        Lazy_copy_<string>      arg_one,
        Lazy_copy_<string>      arg_two,
        Lazy_copy_<string>      arg_three
        )
    {
        if( arg_one.item() == "no_copy" )
        {
            return;     // The case of no copying needed.
        }
        a = move( arg_one.item_copy() );
        b = move( arg_two.item_copy() );
        c = move( arg_three.item_copy() );
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Thingy  x;
    string a = "A", b = "B", c = "C";

    trace( "Call with copying:" );
    x.foo( string( "a" ), b, c );
    trace( "" );
    trace( "Call without copying: " );
    x.foo( string( "no_copy" ), b, c );
}
```

Output when built with `TRACE` defined:

```
: Call with copying:
: <init>( Item&& ): moved
: ensure_is_copy: made copy
: ensure_is_copy: made copy
:
: Call without copying:
: <init>( Item&& ): moved
```

Comment: That's an extra move over just passing by `const&` though.

Comment: @Miral: I don't see that. What case?

Comment: With `const&` there is no copy/move on entry and copy-assignment when assigning to the field.  With the code above, for an rvalue arg there is a move-construct on entry (to the `Lazy_copy_`) and then a move-assignment to the field; and for an lvalue arg there is nothing on entry, then a copy-construct, then a move-assignment.  Not sure if the compiler is allowed to elide that into a single copy-assignment instead.  If not, that's one extra move for lvalues, but rvalues are better (provided that moving twice is cheaper than copying once).

Comment: FWIW, in VS2013 that doesn't compile because it doesn't permit union members to have copy constructors.  In VS2015 it does compile but doesn't elide to a copy-assignment.

Comment: @Miral: Oh, you're right. I guess it's late in the day for me. But if you can live with the extra move for lvalue arg expressions, then you avoid the extra copying for rvalue arg expressions. :)

Comment: @Miral: You can address that concern by providing an `is_reference` accessor. Then client code can choose to discriminate on that to avoid the extra move, i.e., if the `Lazy_copy_` carries a reference, use the `item` method to just copy, instead of using `item_copy` to copy and move. As opposed to passing by value where the move cannot be avoided, and where copies are made regardless of whether they'll be needed.

Comment: Something like `void assign(Item& target) { if (is_reference()) { target = item(); } else { target = move(item_copy()); } }` with `bool is_reference() const { return !!p_callers_item_; }`, right?  (Curse the lack of proper code formatting in comments.)  If I'm following it correctly, that's a single copy-assignment for an lvalue input and a move-construct plus move-assignment for an rvalue input. Still requires knowledge that the type is at least twice as cheap to move as to copy, but that's not bad.   Pity the union trick doesn't work in VS2013... I'll be updating to VS2015 soon but not yet.

Comment: @Miral: I think instead of the pointer plus union one can just use two pointers, and provide a function the returns `T` (instead of reference, although a reference is needed for the ability to use actual argument without creating copy). I wrote that code very much off the cuff, forgetting to provide `is_reference`, and for that matter forgetting to provide a function to give reference to non-`const`, which probably once was the point of the `union`... :) So, just adapt it.